# After scoped `no autodie` the program dies at `*STDOUT`

Tags: perl, scope, autodie

This program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

{
    #use autodie;   # all good when this is uncommented
    no autodie;
}

open my $OLDSTD, '>&', *STDOUT;        #--> line 10 (program fails)
open *STDOUT, '>', 'stdout.out';

say "$$ done";
```

aborts with

```
Undefined subroutine called at problem_no_autodie.pl line 10.
```

To restate the comment in code: if there is a `use autodie;` statement first then all is well. (All is well with only `use autodie;` as well.) Curiously, in the same scope with `no autodie` statement I see no such problems either; only code outside of its scope fails! Kinda anti-scoping, eh?

If this scoped `no autodie` comes *after* the use of `*STDOUT` then it's all good again. Further use of `*STDOUT`, after (the scoped) `no autodie`, fails the program.

There is a [Gotcha](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html#GOTCHAS) mentioned in docs that involves barewords (which I don't fully understand), and the program indeed fails with `STDOUT` -- but I have it as `*STDOUT`.

So it appears that `*STDOUT` is treated as a user's sub, but I don't understand that nor how the scope of `autodie` gets defeated.  (Scope leakage is mentioned as a bug in some versions but in a seemingly unrelated way.)  And there is a practical problem with this.

I don't use `autodie` in my code. But consider this sub, which I do use

```
sub isatty {
    no autodie;
    state $isatty = open(my $tty, '+<', '/dev/tty');
    return $isatty;
}
```

It is legitimate for that `open` to fail, so we have to disable `autodie` in that scope in case the user of the sub has it on. Then is the described behavior going to hurt? Under what circumstances?

I am puzzled by this effect of `no autodie` and by its leakage out of its scope, and by all their strange details. But the real concern is that I am not sure how to protect the code that uses a library like the one above against that behavior, since I don't understand it. Any ideas?

I see this under 5.16.3 (system), 5.26.2 and 5.30.0 (perlbrew) on CentOS 7.8

I *do not* see this behavior on 5.32.0; no failure there.

---

*The `... or die $!` check with `open` didn't make any difference so it's not shown for simplicity.*

Comment: I don't get any errors with 5.26.1 (system) or 5.32.0 (perlbrew) on an Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: @Shawn Interesting.  In particular the fact that two versions where it fails for me bracket the one where it doesn't fail for you.  I installed 5.32.0 under perlbrew -- and it doesn't fail for that one!  Edited question accordingly. So we agree on somethin' :) Thank you for checking it out.

Comment: @Shawn I installed 5.26.1 to test, given ikegami's answer, and the program does fail under it for me!  Perhaps your Ubuntu has it patched (or version upgraded) on 5.26.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This bug](https://github.com/pjf/autodie/issues/69) was introduced in autodie 2.24 and fixed in autodie 2.30.

```
$ ( cd ./autodie-2.23; perl Makefile.PL >&3; make >&3; perl -Mblib ../a.pl && echo ok ) 3>/dev/null
ok

$ ( cd ./autodie-2.24; perl Makefile.PL >&3; make >&3; perl -Mblib ../a.pl && echo ok ) 3>/dev/null
Undefined subroutine called at ../a.pl line 10.

$ ( cd ./autodie-2.29; perl Makefile.PL >&3; make >&3; perl -Mblib ../a.pl && echo ok ) 3>/dev/null
Undefined subroutine called at ../a.pl line 10.

$ ( cd ./autodie-2.30; perl Makefile.PL >&3; make >&3; perl -Mblib ../a.pl && echo ok ) 3>/dev/null
ok

$ ( cd ./autodie-2.31; perl Makefile.PL >&3; make >&3; perl -Mblib ../a.pl && echo ok ) 3>/dev/null
ok
```

(2.30 is not found on CPAN.)

To protect against this issue, add a dependency on autodie 2.30 or higher.

Comment: Thank you. I probably can't have a specific module updated on our production systems (policies etc) so then I'll use `eval` instead of `no autodie`.

Comment: @zdim You could monkey patch the problematic sub. `*Foo::is_atty = sub { ... };` wrapped in a version check (cause that's so much better than upgrading a module...)

Comment: That would force the calling code to only use the "allowed" version of `autodie`? While that is the _right way_ I think I'd have to pass given how and where the lib may get used.  Goes back to mine not understanding _what_ the bug does, so in what circumstances it might bite. But I think that I have that at barely a few places so `eval`-ing instead is easy

Comment: ? No, that won't force the code to use a version of autodie that isn't installed; that would provide a means to avoid using autodie at all.