# `last` while reading file from external command crashes perl

Tags: perl, sigpipe

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.0360;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use Devel::Confess 'color'; # not essential, but better error reporting

open my $view, "zcat a.big.file.vcf.gz|"; # zcat or bcftools
while (<$view>) {
    next unless /^#CHROM\t/;
    last;
}
close $view;
```

the above code crashes with the error

```
Can't close(GLOB(0x55adfa96ebf8)) filehandle: '' at (eval 11)[/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/Fatal.pm:1683] line 74
 at (eval 11)[/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/Fatal.pm:1683] line 74.
    main::__ANON__[(eval 11)[/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/Fatal.pm:1683]:86](GLOB(0x55adfa96ebf8)) called at mwe.pl line 13
Command exited with non-zero status 255
```

However, if I comment out `last` the code runs without a problem, however, the file is *huge* and this makes a significant difference in running time.

The code also works if I remove `close $view` but `close` is proper practice.

How can I run the code with both `last` and `close $view`?

Comment: Your entire loop does nothing. Your sample code has no way of succeeding or failing, beyond exiting unfavourably. It either runs a long time, or a short time. If I were to guess what the errors are about, I would say it is about fatal warnings and autodie. Remove those, and your code will likely improve.

Comment: @TLP I need autodie. The loop does nothing because this is a minimal working example of much larger code

Comment: You never "need" autodie, you can just check return values on your own and `die` where you need to. `autodie` is just a convenience. Although `Fatal.pm` in the error is likely from the warnings pragma, not autodie. That will cause your code to "crash" every time there is a warning. Closing a file handle is not required, it will close automatically when the program ends of the file handle goes out of scope.

Comment: Your example is so minimal that it is almost pointless. Perhaps you should take a look at the core module [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `last` out of reading that process (`zcat` here) and [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close) the pipe, before the process is done writing, the process gets a `SIGPIPE`

> Closing the read end of a pipe before the process writing to it at the other end is done writing results in the writer receiving a SIGPIPE

So as `close` then `wait`s on it it gets a non-zero, and returns false (as seen below). That's all.  The rest -- the program "crashing"  -- is up to `autodie`, which throws an exception. Without `autodie` (or fatal warnings)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Scalar::Util qw(openhandle);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

open my $view, "zcat $file |" or die "Can't pipe-open zcat: $!";

while (<$view>) {
    next unless /^#CHROM\t/;  # (added to my test file)
    say "Matched --> $_";
    last;
}

say "Filehandle good? --> ", openhandle($view) // 'undef';  # GLOB(...)
    
close $view or warn $!  
    ? "Error closing pipe: $!" 
    : "Command exit status: $?";                            # 13

say "Program received a signal ", $? & 127  if $? & 127;    # 13
```

I get `Command exit status: 13`, so `close` didn't return true while `$!` is false. This indicates that the only issue was the non-zero status

> If the filehandle came from a piped open, `close` returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, `$!` will be set to `0`.

We did get a signal, `13` (for `sigpipe`, see `man 7 signal`), what terminated the program and so there was no particular exit code (`$? >> 8` is indeed zero), and no core was dumped (`$? & 128` is zero). See [$? in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$?)

Since the exit status is non-zero `close` returns false and `autodie` throws its exception.

---

So what to do with this?

That `close` must stay and be checked, of course.

Even if the `SIGPIPE` sent to `zcat` could be ignored, as I've seen claimed in some docs, you wouldn't want that -- it's there on purpose, to let the writer know that there are no readers so that it can stop!

Finally, it is `autodie` that kills the program, and it can be disabled lexically. (This satisfies the "need" for `autodie` stated in a comment.) So put this pipe reading and early close in a block

```
READ_FROM_PIPE: { 
    no autodie qw(close);
    # do the pipe-open, read from the pipe, close() it...
};
# rest of code
```

Don't forget to suitably adjust your other error handling in this code.

(I've had weird experience with `no autodie` "leakage" out of its scope, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64096831/4653379). But that was a different case, and fixed by `autodie` 2.30 so hopefully not of concern.)

Another option is to wrap all this, or just the `close()`, in `eval` instead.  This is considered good practice, they say in docs. Then see how to work with [autodie exceptions](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie#EXCEPTIONS).

Comment: Re "*As for why `$!` is emtpy*", I meant the `''` of `Can't close(GLOB(0x55adfa96ebf8)) filehandle: ''` This is probably the result of `close` error handling needs to be quite different for for `open -|` handles

Comment: @ikegami  Oh, right, that ... looks like that's on `autodie`? I mean there is no error to quit over really, just that non-zero exit (with signal code only).  It seems that when a subprocess is killed by a signal there is nothing in `$!`, so `autodie` should either add a message or just leave it altogether?

Comment: @ikegami Or I suppose `close` should fill `$!` for when a signal is all that there is.  But then that'd be for other calls as well -- I tried with killing a `system` command externally and I got `15` in `$?` and empty `$!`